# Simple return statement error

Tags: java, return

I'm trying to make a program that returns a letter grade for whatever number grade you put into it but java keeps telling me I'm missing a return statement. I've tried changing char to void to int but none of those worked. I'm still a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

```
class Grades
{

public static char getGrade(int x)
{
    char A, B, C, D, F;
    if((x>=90) && (x<=100))
        return 'A';
    if((x>=80) && (x<=89))
        return 'B';
    if((x>=70) && (x<=79))
        return 'C';
    if((x>=65) && (x<=69))
        return 'D';
    if(x<65)
        return 'F';
}

public static char getGrade(int y, int z)
{
    int w = ((y + z)/2);
    return getGrade(w);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("64 gets the grade " + getGrade(64));
    System.out.println("99 gets the grade " + getGrade(99));
    System.out.println("73 and 91 gets the grade " + getGrade(73,91));
}
}
```

Every time I use this code I always receive the error:

Grades.java:17: error: missing return statement
    }
Why is this?

Comment: What value should be returned if none of your `if`s will work (remember that compiler things that `int x` can be value outside of `0-100` range).

Comment: The perfect candidate for an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always have a 100% probability to return something, which was not the case here.

```
public int returnAnInt(int a){
    if (a > 0) return 10;
}
```

This code wouldn't work because it is not guarenteed that `a` is always superior to `0`. Imagine have `-1` as a parameter.. What would it return?

Check the correction :

```
public int returnAnInt (int a){
    if (a > 0) 10;
    else return 0;
}
```

Because you're anticipating all the possibilities, this will compile.

You can set `F` as the default return value here :

```
public static char getGrade(int x)
{
    if((x>=90) && (x<=100))
        return 'A';
    if((x>=80) && (x<=89))
        return 'B';
    if((x>=70) && (x<=79))
        return 'C';
    if((x>=65) && (x<=69))
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'F';
}
```

It will work in this condition but is not optimal in most situations. It is up to you to find the best correction possible to your own code.

I gave you the right path here.

Comment: It doesn't quite give you a "default", it gives you an option if the condition around the "D" case fails.

Comment: Which is a default in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't want to mislead anyone into thinking that this is the way to provide a default return value for a whole bunch of open `if` statements, though.  It is in that it provides *some* value should the rest fail, but it really isn't in that it only provides a value in case the *last* one fails.  A bit of a technically to be sure, but still enough to get me a bit riled.

Comment: @Makoto, I get it. I'll edit the answer but I think it is the job of OP to find the right corrections after been given the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You're not guaranteed to return anything from your if statement.  You have to add an `else` or return some default value.

If you want to keep the code the same, then place `return 'F';` at the end of the method.  No need to check if it is an F; it is by elimination.

For instance, that would mean the code would look as follows.

```
public static char getGrade(int x) {
    if((x>=90) && (x<=100)) {
        return 'A';
    }
    if((x>=80) && (x<=89)) {
        return 'B';
    }
    if((x>=70) && (x<=79)) {
        return 'C';
    }
    if((x>=65) && (x<=69)) {
        return 'D';
    }
    return 'F';
}
```

As an alternative, consider including `else if` statements, since that would make this a bit clearer.

Comment: Shouldn't he place some other value at the end of the function that won't confuse him if something went wrong with the code above like using return 0 at the end? I think it would be better practice

Comment: I'll edit this answer when I get to a keyboard, but there's no reason to introduce a bogus sentinel value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot ensure that there is a return. Have a look at the following example:

```
public boolean mod2(int a){
    if(a % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    if(a % 2 != 0)
        return false;
}
```

This method will return for any given value but the compiler can only check snytax not semantics. And therefore the code is not compilable.

You need something like a default case which will match if none of the above statements will match.
With the code above it will be:

```
public boolean mod2(int a){
    if(a % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can avoid repeating the grade boundaries by using TreeMap:

```
public static char getGrade(int x) {
    NavigableMap<Integer, Character> grades = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>();
    grades.put(90, 'A');
    grades.put(80, 'B');
    grades.put(70, 'C');
    grades.put(65, 'D');
    grades.put(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 'F');
    return grades.floorEntry(x).getValue();
}
```

If you know that the number grades are non-negative, you can replace Integer.MIN_VALUE with 0 for better readability.

If, on the other hand, you want the method to reject number grades higher than 100, you will need to add some validation at the top of the method.

If the grade calculation is performance critical, it is better to initialize the map just once, somewhere outside the getGrade method.